# Variable within SUMIFS

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

I have an Excel workbook which has multiple sheets. Each sheet represent a customer's monthly income and the last column of each sheet has total income. So Column "S" in each sheet has total income.

Now, I have a summary sheet in which I want to show total income of each of those customers whose income is appearing in those individual sheets. I'm using "SUMIFS" but I have to change formula for every customer because every customer's income is in different sheet and each sheet has it's own address/reference even though the columns are same.

My question is, can I make the sheet's name variable in my summary sheet so that I don't have to change formula for every customer. I can just add the sheet's name in my summary sheet and drag down the formula so that formula can pick sheet's name from there.

I hope I'm making sense.

Let me know if this is doable without Macros/VBA.

Thanks.

Comment: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6?

Comment: Sounds like you want INDIRECT to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes you solve it without VBA, use the formula indirect and enter the sheet name as a string or reference.**

String:

> =INDIRECT("SheetName!A2")

Reference example - write sheet name in cell A1 and the formula will look for the answer in cell A2 for that sheet:

> =INDIRECT(A1&"!A2")

If you use spaces in a sheet you must also add a single quote ' before and after the name.

Avoid mixing references to sheets with and without spaces to make it simpler, 
otherwise try

> =IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&A1&"'!A2");INDIRECT(A1&"!A2"))